# Write a Web server quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, internet

Write a program that accepts HTTP requests on any port of your choice above 1024, and responds to requests on any URL of your choice with its own source code. It must work with, at least, Firefox and Chrome. The code should be delivered <s>as `text/plain`</s> *(removed requirement because none of the answers but one met it)* with no formatting. There is no restriction on the URL, except that it must not be used to encode any portion of the code; serving on the root is encouraged and likely the shortest solution, but is not required.

Standard quine restrictions apply. Web server frameworks are allowed, but are considered separate languages, so, for example, a Python + Flask answer does not compete with a stdlib-only Python answer.

Bonus for HTTPS support:

| HTTPS | HTTP | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No | Yes | None |
| Yes | No | 10% |
| Yes | Yes | 15% |
| Yes | Redirects to HTTPS | 20% |

If you do include HTTPS support, you may access the certificate by any reasonable means.

Comment: Does it need to respond to multiple requests?

Comment: @gsitcia no, except that to claim the 20% bonus for redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, it must be able to handle the initial HTTP request and the resulting HTTPS request. Otherwise, it's okay if it closes after one request.

Comment: Is it okay if the port is chosen randomly at startup?

Comment: @corvus_192 that is okay, as long as there is some indication of what port is used, such as printing it to stdout

Comment: Is it cheating to just serve the source file?

Comment: @noodleman yes, a quine that reads its source file is cheating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## JavaScript ([Deno](https://deno.com/)), <s>60</s> 52 bytes

```javascript
function f(){Deno.serve(_=>new Response(f+"f()")}f()
```

[Try it at the Deno Deploy Playground!](https://dash.deno.com/playground/web-server-quine) (Outdated).

Saved 5 bytes by using a `function` declaration instead of an arrow function, because Deno runs in strict mode where you need `let` in variable declarations:

```
let f=_=>…`let f=${f};f()`…;f()
function f(){…f+"f()"…}f()
// allowed in Node, but not in Deno:
f=_=>…`f=${f};f()`…;f()
```

Here's an alternate version that doesn't use function stringifying, <s>stolen</s> slightly modified from [Don Hastings's wonderful quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155125/108687), for **88 bytes**:

```javascript
let Q="let q=Q.link()[8];Deno.serve(()=>new Response(`let Q=${q+Q+q};eval(Q)`))";eval(Q)
```

[Try it at the Deno Deploy Playground!](https://dash.deno.com/playground/non-stringifying-wsquine)

Answer (score 10):

## Javascript (Node.js), 77 bytes

```
(f=x=>require('http').createServer((_,x)=>x.end(`(f=${f})()`)).listen(1e4))()
```

Comment: 76 bytes with express: `(f=x=>require('express')().get('',(_,r)=>r.end(`(f=${f})()`)).listen(1e4))()`

Comment: @corvus_192 Not vanilla and `Web server frameworks are allowed, but are considered separate languages`

Comment: I know, but the code is so similar, I didn't want to post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 176 bytes

```python
_='_=%r;a=%r;exec(a)';a="from socket import*;s=socket();s.bind(('',9000));s.listen()\nwhile 1:q,c=s.accept();q.send(b'HTTP/1.0\\n\\n'+(_%(_,a)).encode());q=q.recv(999)";exec(a)
```

Listens to any requests to `localhost:9000`.

Only listening for one request saves 11 bytes

#### 165 bytes

```python
_='_=%r;a=%r;exec(a)';a="from socket import*;s=socket();s.bind(('',9000));s.listen();q,c=s.accept();q.send(b'HTTP/1.0\\n\\n'+(_%(_,a)).encode());q.recv(999)";exec(a)
```

Both browsers (Firefox 120.0 & Chromium 119.0.6045.159) seem to be happy to accept responses with no status code.

#### 147 bytes (only Firefox)

```python
_='_=%r;a=%r;exec(a)';a="from socket import*;s=socket();s.bind(('',9000));s.listen();q,c=s.accept();q.send((_%(_,a)).encode());q.recv(999)";exec(a)
```

Firefox still supports HTTP/0.9

#### 146 bytes (only Chromium)

```python
_='_=%r;a=%r;exec(a)';a="from socket import*;s=socket();s.bind(('',9000));s.listen();s.accept()[0].send(b'HTTP\\n\\n'+(_%(_,a)).encode())";exec(a)
```

Chromium doesn't seem to require the '/1.0' part, and also doesn't care if the server closes the connection early (?)

Comment: Can you replace `9000` with `9e3` or even `-1` for port `65535`?

Comment: @ATaco I just tried it, 9e3 complains about being a float, and -1 gives an OverflowError

Comment: Huh, I wonder why Firefox requires Content-Length?

Comment: Actually testing it locally it's intermittent...

Comment: You can remove the space after `import` in `from socket import *`.

Comment: For me Firefox seems to likes to make an additional "warm-up" request which defeats the "one request" version.

Comment: Also, you're not actually waiting for a request before sending the reply, which might also be confusing Firefox.

Comment: @Neil I haven't seen Firefox make any additional requests (maybe the favicon?). Anyways, waiting for the request after sending the reply seems to let Firefox work without the Content-Length header (my best guess was that Firefox wants to close the connection itself, but getting rid of the `q=` in the looping version makes it not work, so maybe it's a race condition on whether the request gets acknowledged?)

Comment: (Firefox does request the favicon after a successful page load. I don't know about the failure case.)

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3 + http.server, <s>134</s> 95 bytes

```python
exec(b:="import os;open('.txt','w').write('exec(b:=%r)'%b);os.system('python -m http.server')")
```

Uses a simple Exec quine and writes the contents of it to `.txt` and then launches a simple webserver in the current folder via the `python -m http.server` tool. Hosts on port `8000` at `/.txt`

Very rarely use Python, so it might be golfable...

[image]

Comment: I haven't tested it, but knowing Python, can't you remove the space at `) as`?

Comment: You can provide a single string for the `call` argument: `call(['python','-m','http.server'])` -> `call('python -m http.server')`, removing 6 bytes.

Comment: why the very long `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system`?

Comment: I removed the text/plain requirement because the other answers weren't meeting it, so I think you can save three bytes now with a one-character file name.

Comment: @Somebody Unfortunately has to be `.txt` as otherwise it tries to download the file, rather than render it.

Comment: @ATaco I think the challenge was to return an HTTP response with the source code, so IMO downloading is valid

Answer (score 6):

## Python + Flask, 151 bytes

```
from flask import*;a=Flask('');s="from flask import*;a=Flask('');s=%s\n@a.route('/')\ndef i():return s%%repr(s)"
@a.route('/')
def i():return s%repr(s)
```

Doesn't show newlines as it's `text/html`. Visible on `localhost:5000` and/or `127.0.0.1:5000`. The obvious python and flask solution.

To be executed as a flask app. For example (on windows at least), assuming the file is called `flask_app.py`:

```
> set FLASK_APP=flask_app
> flask run
```

[image]

Comment: Can't be bothered to test it, but does [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chLSexOFshM7cgv6hEyzrR1g3E11BX17QutlUiqEK1KCbPIVGvKL@0JFVDXR8ohszRKFZVLdZUQhcr1vz/HwA) work by any chance?

Comment: Why don't you use exec to run thethe code in the string and avoid having to duplicate it?

Comment: "Doesn't show newlines as it's text/plain."  What?  did you mean text/html?

Comment: @OskarSkog yes, I indeed meant text/html

Answer (score 5):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org) + [LuaSockets](https://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/home.html), 138 bytes.

```lua
b="t=require('socket').tcp()t:bind('*',-1)t:listen()c=t:accept()c:receive()c:send(('HTTP/1.0 200\\n\\nb=%qload(b)()'):format(b))"load(b)()
```

Stores the main code in `b` and loads it, then wraps it in `('...b=%qload(b)()'):format(b)` to quine it.
The webserver listens for any TCP connection on port `65535` (-1) and just immediately dumps the bare-minimum HTTP response to it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Racket `#lang web-server/insta`, 199 bytes

```scheme
#lang web-server/insta (define-syntax-rule(S n f)(define n(f'(S n f))))(S start (λ (s) (λ r (response/xexpr (~a "#lang web-server/insta (define-syntax-rule(S n f)(define n(f'(S n f))))" (~s s))))))
```

Running the program (e.g. with `racket golf.rkt` or in DrRacket) prints something like:

```
Your Web application is running at http://localhost:34163/servlets/standalone.rkt.
Stop this program at any time to terminate the Web Server.
```

and automatically launches your default browser with the page. Stopping the program (e.g. with Ctrl-C or DrRacket's Stop button) prints:

```
Web Server stopped.
```

Depending on your definition of "standard library", `web-server/insta` might be part of Racket's standard library. It is included in the "main distribution" you'd download from https://download.racket-lang.org.

### HTTPS Only, 241 bytes

```scheme
#lang web-server (define-syntax-rule(S s)(s'(S s)))(S (λ (s) (local-require web-server/servlet-env) (serve/servlet (λ r (response/xexpr (~a "#lang web-server (define-syntax-rule(S s)(s'(S s)))" (~s s)))) #:ssl? #t #:server-root-path ".")))
```

This uses `server-cert.pem` and `private-key.pem` from the current directory. It serves on `https://localhost:8000/servlets/standalone.rkt`.

### HTTP→HTTPS, 356 bytes

```scheme
#lang web-server (define-syntax-rule(S s)(s'(S s)))(S (λ (s) (local-require web-server/servlet-env) (thread (λ () (serve/servlet (λ r (redirect-to "https://localhost:8443/servlets/standalone.rkt"))))) (serve/servlet (λ r (response/xexpr (~a "#lang web-server (define-syntax-rule(S s)(s'(S s)))" (~s s)))) #:port 8443 #:ssl? #t #:server-root-path ".")))
```

Same certificate configuration as above, but listens on `http://localhost:8000/servlets/standalone.rkt` and `https://localhost:8443/servlets/standalone.rkt`.

### Original: With `text/plain`, 263 bytes

```scheme
#lang web-server/insta (define-syntax-rule (S n f) (define n (f '(S n f)))) (S start (λ (s) (λ r (response/output #:mime-type #"text/plain;charset=utf-8" (λ (o) (fprintf o "#lang web-server/insta (define-syntax-rule (S n f) (define n (f '(S n f)))) ~s" s))))))
```

Comment: It's a shame we can't save a few more bytes by removing spaces in the body of `start`; I tried, and (I think because of the macro) the response puts them back in.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I tried, too: the issue is that `write` emits conventional whitespace, not the minimum possible whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 149 bytes

```powershell
$f={($h=[Net.HttpListener]::new()).Prefixes.Add("http://*:9090/")
$h|% s*t
(($r=$h|% G*t|% R*e)|% o*).Write([byte[]]("`$f={$f}"|% t*y))
$r.Close()}
```

Run it using `&$f`
Listens on port `9090`
Replies only once and does not free the port

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](http://rust-lang.org), 385 bytes

```rust
use std::io::*;fn main(){write!(std::net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap().accept().unwrap().0,r"HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type:text/plain
Content-Length:385

{1}{1}{}","\x22#);}",r#"use std::io::*;fn main(){write!(std::net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap().accept().unwrap().0,r"HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type:text/plain
Content-Length:385

{1}{1}{}","\x22#);}",r#""#);}
```

When run as the main.rs file in a cargo project with `cargo run`, this program waits until you go to 127.0.0.1:8080 in your browser (this is what `accept()` does) and then sends over its source code and ends.

Answer (score 1):

## C (`gcc -lws2_32` + `winsock2.h`), 408 bytes

```c
Z;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(9,M);sprintf(M,S="HTTP/1.1 200 OK%c%cContent-Length: 408%c%c%c%cZ;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(9,M);sprintf(M,S=%c%s%c,13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,448,0);}",13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,448,0);}
```

This uses the Windows Socket 2 API. I have made many questionable choices for the sake of the golf, so there is likely some instability. Listens to an arbitrary number of HTTP requests on port `1025`. Compiled with `gcc server.c -o server -lws2_32` (e.g.).

### Verification

In Firefox:

[image: A picture of the Quine in action on Firefox, showing the full code from earlier.]

[![A picture of the Quine in action on Firefox, showing the full code from earlier.][2]][2]

Here is the Ruby test harness I used to verify integrity:

```rb
require "net/http"
puts "Waiting for server to start..."
server_process = IO.popen("server.exe") { |server|
    3.times { |i|
        response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI("http://localhost:1025")).body
        puts "Response ##{i} obtained:"
        puts response
        
        puts "Same as server.c?"
        puts File.read("server.c") == response
    }

    puts "Killing server..."
    Process.kill("KILL", server.pid)
}
```

Which, when run:

```c
λ ruby test-server.rb
Waiting for server to start...
Response #0 obtained:
Z;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(9,M);sprintf(M,S="HTTP/1.1 200 OK%c%cContent-Length: 408%c%c%c%cZ;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(9,M);sprintf(M,S=%c%s%c,13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,448,0);}",13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,448,0);}
Same as server.c?
true
Response #1 obtained:
Z;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(9,M);sprintf(M,S="HTTP/1.1 200 OK%c%cContent-Length: 408%c%c%c%cZ;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(9,M);sprintf(M,S=%c%s%c,13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,448,0);}",13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,448,0);}
Same as server.c?
true
Response #2 obtained:
Z;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(9,M);sprintf(M,S="HTTP/1.1 200 OK%c%cContent-Length: 408%c%c%c%cZ;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(9,M);sprintf(M,S=%c%s%c,13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,448,0);}",13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,448,0);}
Same as server.c?
true
Killing server...
```

### Explanation

Using fairly standard quining techniques, although my gcc on Windows does not support the POSIX extension for referencing existing `*printf` arguments (as in [this quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122856/31957), so we must duplicate quite a few constants. At one point, I tried using unprintable characters in multiple places (`Q="\x02\x00''"), but that seemed to not work well with browsers interfacing with the server.

Here is an expanded version, producing the same output as above (so no longer a quine itself), but commented:

```c
// our socket description integer
Z;
// the server code contained here
main() {
    char
        // our format string to be passed into sprintf
        *S,
        // shorthand for our struct sockaddr_in, which is passed to bind and accept
        // struct sockaddr_in address = { .sin_family = AF_INET /*=2*/, .sin_port = htons(1025) /*=0x0401*/ };
        // [NOTE 1]
        Q[16] = { 2, 0, 4, 1 },
        // M serves two purposes: 1. to be a sprintf buffer and 2. to be allocated memory to allow WSAStartup to run without crashing
        *M = malloc(999);
    // usually, wVersionRequired is version of windows sockets required (e.g. 2.1 would be 0x0201 = 513), and would be expressed like MAKEWORD(2,3)
    // while wVersionRequired can't be 0, from testing, 9 seems to work.
    WSAStartup(9, M);
    // the main quine section
    sprintf(
        // the message buffer
        M,
        // the format string
        S = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK%c%cContent-Length: 412%c%c%c%cZ;main(){char*S,Q[16]={2,0,4,1},*M=malloc(999);WSAStartup(514,M);sprintf(M,S=%c%s%c,13,10,13,10,13,10,34,S,34);bind(Z=socket(2,1,0),Q,16);for(listen(Z,3);;)send(accept(Z,Q,0),M,452,0);}",
        // \r\n after 200 OK
        13, 10,
        // \r\n\r\n after headers
        13, 10, 13, 10
        // " followed by our string followed by ",
        34, S, 34,
    );
    // binds our socket to our target address
    bind(
        // creates a socket with a particular configuration.
        // socket(
        //    address family specification; AF_INET == 2, and represents IPv4
        //    the socket type specification; SOCK_STREAM == 1, and represents two-way connections
        //    the protocol subtype; 0, since we don't need to specify anything further
        // )
        // returns a socket description integer
        Z = socket(2,1,0),
        // the string from earlier, reinterpreted as an address struct
        Q,
        // the size of the address struct; expected to be 16
        16
    );
    // infinite loop
    for(
        // but first, to save a semicolon, start listening on our socket
        // we arbitrarily choose 3 as a backlog queue size
        listen(Z, 3);
        ;
    ) {
        // reply to the request with the message
        send(
            // accept a request on the address for our socket
            accept(Z, Q, 0),
            // the message to report
            M,
            // its length
            452,
            // flags; none chosen
            0
        );
    }
}
```

Note 1: We can omit the more precise property specification `.sin_addr = { .s_addr = INADDR_ANY }` as `INADDR_ANY == 0`. If we did need it, we do have the golfy option `Q={2,1025,{0}}`.

Comment: I just noticed it doesn't have to respond to multiple requests. I'll change the code in a bit.

Answer (score -1):

## Bash + ncat (from nmap), 106 bytes

```
h='HTTP/2\r\n\r\n';s='h=\47%s\47;s=\47%s\47;printf $h$s $h $s|ncat -lp2222';printf $h$s $h $s|ncat -lp2222
```

Comment: it does not return the souce code

Comment: It does for me in Firefox and Chrome.